# What is the query to fetch result from database in deployd server?

Tags: deployd

I am new in delpoyd server and need to validate email address already exist. 
I read his document but unable to achieve result as expected.

According to deployd doc, I was trying this.

```
dpd['to-do'].get(query, function (result) {   console.log(result); });
```

Please help me if anyone know.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use for validating whether email already exists.I use this code in the Validate event.The need for checking the method *'PUT'* is to prevent users from changing the email id to something that already exists after registering.

```
function validate(result, field) {
    if (method === 'PUT') {
        if (result.length === 0) {
        } else if (!(result.length === 1 && result[0].id === id)) {
            error(field, field + " is already in use");
        }
    } else if (result.length !== 0) {
        error(field, field + " is already in use");
    }
}
if (!internal) {
    var email;
    var method = ctx.method;
    email = {
        "email": this.email
    };
    dpd.users.get(email, function (result) {
        validate(result, "email");
    });
}
```